# How to get a string in bold (without NSMutableString)

Tags: nsstring, string-formatting

It seems so obvious but I haven't found the answer :-(...

Does anyone know how we can define a new NSString and have it bold (or italic). I know we can do it with Attributed things, but the problem is that I understood that we need NSMutableString and then I cannot convert this MutableString into NSString (to use it later in [NSString stringWithFormat...]) despite some propositions seen somewhere.

(I am generating a PDF and have not discovered yet other ways to have a bolded string in the document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString` doesn't represent any styling information. With only the NSString representation there's no way to know if the string is supposed to be displayed in bold, italic, 72 point, or Comic Sans.

This styling information ("attributes") is represented in an NSAttributedString.

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello world!";
NSAttributedString *myBoldString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString
                                                             attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:72.0] }];
```

This creates a string with styling information. If you're wanting to display this string on a UILabel, for example, you'll want to set the `.attributedText` property rather than `.text`.

```
self.label.attributedText = myBoldString;
```

The separation of data (the string contents) from presentation (the style attributes) is a common theme in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Oh that was fast, thank you!

So if I understand correctly since I am getting my PDF content from a huge [NSString stringWithFormat:...] it will be impossible to get formatted text?

And I have to find an other way to generate a PDF if I want bold (attributed) text?

Thanks!

Tricho

Comment: I'm not sure what code you're using to generate the PDF. If it accepts NSAttributedString that'd be one way to do it.

Comment: I am using the one mentioned in Apple documentation. To get the text: CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)textView.text, NULL); if (currentText)...
I think it should be possible to enter my string (instead of textView.text) and values for having it bolded right after (instead of the third NULL argument). But is it not quite tedious to deal with multiple CFAttributedStringRefs (setting attributes for each of them in the same way of "current text") if we have a long text?

Comment: I did not see in Apple doc if we could concatenate multiple CFAttributedStringRefs (something like it would be with NSString: NSString stringWithFormat:%@%@, CFAttrStr1, CFAttrStr2). But maybe it is possible and the easiest way is to define like this all the different strings I need with a specific format and then transform it in a big CFAttrStringRef before dealing with the framesetter and so on stuff...